# How to configure Craft From for a form roulet/carousel?

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm making a website where the 1st submit of the form needs to be sent to 6 people on a list, the second submit of that same form needs to be send to the next 6 persons on the list, and so on.

I also would like to store the number of form submits every person in the list has received.

I was wondering if this is feasible with the Contact Form plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It's not natively possible, but it's doable.

The plugin does support [dynamic recipients](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/tree/v1#dynamically-adding-email-recipients-requires-craft-25).  I'm assuming that the rotating list of people is going to be stored in a database table or some other data source, though.  So in order to pull in the next correct group of people to send to, you'd need to write a [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) so you could run your own business logic.

> I also would like to store the number of form submits every person in the list has received.

When grabbing the next group of people to send to, your plugin would increment a tally for each of the people in the list and save it back out to a database table or other data store.